# syntax for declaring templated function pointer in C++ with keyword using

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, declaration

consider

```
template<typename T>
struct auxiliary
{
  typedef std::unique_ptr<T> (*creator)(std::vector<double>const&);
};
template<typename T>
using creator = typename auxiliary<T>::creator;
```

I wonder how to declare `creator` without `auxiliary`, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
using creator = ???
```

Comment: In a template alias, there shouldn't be anything between `using` and the identifier.

Comment: okay, but that's not the answer.

Comment: No, that's why it's a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
using creator = std::unique_ptr<T> (*)(std::vector<double> const&);
```